# Excel - Multiply contents of cell by 12, only once

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update values entered into cells in `Column A`. I have the following script which works as expected, almost. It updates the cell, but then continues to update until it reaches an exponentially large number.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        intcolumn = Target.Column
        introw = Target.Row
        Cells(introw, intcolumn) = Cells(introw, intcolumn) * "12"
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there a way to make it so that I can make it so I can enter any number in A? and have it only multiply by 12 once? (1 = 12, 2 = 24, 3 = 36, 4 = 48, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your change is triggering the Worksheet_Change event again. You need to have some kind of flag to keep track of it:

```
Private changeFlag As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 And Not changeFlag Then
        changeFlag = True
        intcolumn = Target.Column
        introw = Target.Row
        Cells(introw, intcolumn).Value = Cells(introw, intcolumn).Value * 12
    Else
        changeFlag = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying the cell value triggers the `Worksheet_Change` event, which is triggering this macro. So, when you enter "1" in to cell A1, this is a change that causes multiplication 1*12=12, but **this** is also a change, which causes 12*12=144, which is also a change, etc., which is why it's repeating.

This should fix it, disable events before performing the operation, then re-enable events before exiting the subroutine:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 1 Then
Application.EnableEvents = False 'Prevent looping based on the 'change' caused by multiplication
    intcolumn = Target.Column
    introw = Target.Row
    Cells(introw, intcolumn) = Cells(introw, intcolumn) * "12"
Application.EnableEvents = True 'allow events again
End If
End Sub
```